# TypeScript typeof and class constructor problem

Tags: typescript

I have a map like this:

```js
  const map = {
    a: ClassA,
    b: ClassB,
    c: ClassC,
  }
```

which maps to different classes. and I have this function, which is returning instance of a class mapped by a key in map object:

```js
const conf = {};

type VersionMap = typeof map;
type Versions = keyof VersionMap;

const getter = <T extends Versions>(ver: T): VersionMap[T] => new map[ver](conf);
```

But problem is that typeof is referencing to class constructor, not an instance so I got an error. How can I solve that issue without creating second type?

Comment: Have you checked with specific with dot operator like map.a, map.b etc?. Because just map would give the whole thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some small misconception here on how classes are typed.
Let's assume, for abbreviation here, that we have two classes `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

```js
class ClassA {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Class A");
  }
}

class ClassB {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Class B");
  }
}
```

Creating the map object is easy, but I think, it would have been easier to first describe an interface on what this object is supposed to hold. But as in your example, I proceed without one.

```js
const map = {
  a: ClassA,
  b: ClassB,
};
```

Now comes the tricky part - Typings.
First I want to extract all keys of the map object.
Therefore I'll create a new type called: `Keys`

```
// Type contains: "a" | "b"
type Keys = keyof typeof map;
```

Next I need all associated values for each key.
To achieve this, create a new type at the index of `Keys`.

```js
// Type contains: typeof ClassA | typeof ClassB
type Values = typeof map[Keys];
```

The getter function should return an instance of a class `T`. But the `Values` type contains all classes as `typeof ClassA | typeof ClassB` which is equal to `new() => ClassA | new() => ClassB`.
Thus the type of `ClassA | ClassB` is not compatible.

So let's craft a seperate type to get rid of this. The type should return the instance type of a class - just `ClassA` or `ClassB`.
Or so to say, the return type of `new SomeClass()` operation.

```js
type ReturnType<T> = T extends new() => infer R ? R : never;
```

If you want to read up on conditional types in TypeScript, I highly recommend reading this blog post: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/conditional-types-in-typescript
Let's add the final piece:

```js
const conf = {};
const getter = (ver: Keys): ReturnType<Values> => new map[ver]();
```

FYI: I did change the naming of `VersionMap` to `Values` and `Version` to `Keys` as I think it's easier to understand what each of those types is supposed to do. But feel free to change them to your needs.